# Automatic updater for my Application in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue with my automatic updater. It keeps on telling my customers that there is an update available and downloads it for them, even though they are already using the latest version. In VB my assembly is 1.0.0.0 and in my newversion.txt dropbox link the version is also 1.0.0.0 - So both match perfectly. I tried to code it myself, and it's the same issue, so I then tried an open source...Still the same issue. Here is what I have;

```
Public Class Form3

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    CheckForUpdates()
End Sub

Public Sub CheckForUpdates()

    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2m4s9umxq0i471/newestversion.txt")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion

    If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
        Button1.Text = ("No new updates")
        Button1.Enabled = False

    Else

        Button1.Text = ("An update is available")
        Button1.Enabled = True
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qcp8qxv7icexij/Twitch%20Suite-HF.exe")

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

EDIT: The code is completely right! It was my fault, use someone else don't use dropbox. Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if you're reading the required version? 
Why don't you try comparing the versions directly; `newestversion = currentversion` instead of `newestversion.Contains(currentversion)`?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK newestversion = currentversion doesn't work. It does the same as newversion.contains(currentversion) - Are my dropbox links correct? In my dropbox folder there is a public>socialstamp and within that socialstamp folder there is a newversion.txt and example.exe of the current up to date version.

Comment: If both are of type `string`, why doesn't it work? And have you debugged to see the values of `newestversion` and `currentversion`?

Comment: The code is completely right! It was my fault, use someone else don't use dropbox. Thanks.

Comment: `String.Contains` is still a bad idea. Someone installs version `1.0.0.0` and then doesn't use your product for quite a long time. They come back to use your product, and in the meantime, you've worked your way all the way up to version 11. Unfortunately, `"11.0.0.0".Contains("1.0.0.0")` is `True` and so they don't get the update.

Comment: Note that you can use a technology like ClickOnce to perform automatic updating - no point reinventing the wheel!

Comment: Stanislav was right, you have to make it a direct download but it would be better not to use dropbox beacause links may be disabled if they get used too often. And I think you can just replace www.dropbox with dl.dropbox to make it a direct download (but that might be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem! The answer is simple :)
Your original download link for the newestversion.txt is https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2m4s9umxq0i471/newestversion.txt So the link must be direct link, because the updater cannot look for updates properly. So to fix the problem just add ?dl=1 at the end of the download link, when you add the ?dl=1 at the end the link will be that https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2m4s9umxq0i471/newestversion.txt?dl=1
Cogratulations! When you edited the download link you now have properly updater feature !